# Run "helm upgrade" but suppress warnings

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to upgrade a Helm chart but have warnings about deprecated API's be suppressed from being sent to standard error. I still want errors to appear.

Is there a built-in way to do this, something like "help upgrade --suppress-warnings"?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in way to do this in Helm. You will have to use a workaround such as redirecting standard error to /dev/null when running the Helm upgrade command. For example:

helm upgrade  2>/dev/null